# Searching within a ListView

Tags: android, listview, search, android-edittext

i have a search functionality for an app i am developing and i implemented a sliding menu. In the sliding menus right view, there is an edit text search box but since my app is an offline app, i want to search a listview using an adapter and not a database, i have implemented my code but when i run it, nothing happens, the logcat gives me no errors as well, can someone pls help me check my code out to see if i have any errors.

```
    public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
EditText inputSearch;
ArrayList<String> testArrayList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_right);



    String [] testArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.allArrays);
    testArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(testArray));

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMenuRight);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testArrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            SearchActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: I solved it myself...i am supposed to implement the search in a layout not as an independent activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plaese see this search in listview...

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: no,check my code that i posted and the one from that blog...it is correct i think but i don't know why it is not running.